# MySQL timestamp 30 day validity from moment of creation

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

What I am trying to do here is adding an `30 DAYS` to the `timestamp` when the session key was created.

```
SELECT * FROM `sessions` 
WHERE (`timestamp` + INTERVAL 30 DAY) <= UTC_TIMESTAMP()
```

And then checking it to the current time.

---

But this doesn't work because the session was created just a few days ago. So the `timestamp` is way larger than `UTC_TIMESTAMP` (the current time).

I can ADD another condition `AND (timestamp + INTERVAL 30 DAY) >= UTC_TIMESTAMP()`, but I would have to calculate the interval again.

---

Is there a more efficient way to have this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
`timestamp` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

Comment: My time is kept as datetime(6). I've tried with `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` and `UTC_TIMESTAMP` getting 0 rows.

Comment: Can you please run this query and report back the results? It will be helpful in debugging this issue:
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), MIN(`timestamp`) as min_time, MAX(`timestamp`) as max_time from `sessions`

Comment: min and max time are the same at `2018-09-08 18:33:36.000000`. Thats cause I've only got the one session I test with.

Comment: Edited my answer, try the new condition please.

Comment: Works. Why would I use `DATE_SUB(UTC_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)` over `(UTC_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 40 DAY)` are there any advantages?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure on the logic you are looking for, but as far as "more efficient way":

your original condition of: `(timestamp + INTERVAL 30 DAY) <= UTC_TIMESTAMP()`

is usually better handled as: `timestamp <= (UTC_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)`

In your original, MySQL will apply the addition of the interval to every row's `timestamp` value (and end up ignoring any indexes if you have them); in the rewrite I provided, the interval should be subtracted only once from the result of UTC_TIMESTAMP(), and taking advantage of indexed on `timestamp` is still an option.

Summary: When possible, apply calculations to the sides of conditions/comparisons that are not dependent on the row data.

Comment: You can look up about [sargeable](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/28838/sargeable) query.

Comment: I'v implemented this `timestamp <= (UTC_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 40 DAY)`. And I don't get any results. Went as far back as 500 days.

Comment: Your using the wrong comparation. should be `timestamp >=` think about it. Today is september 10, substract 30 days. if timestamp is >= august 10 the session is valid

Comment: @Borsn from the data you've mentioned, that sounds like the correct result. You have no data older than a few days, looking further back won't find more; as Juan said, check that your condition is appropriate; the one in your comment is looking for "data older than 40 days"

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Now that works great. I was going off the suggestion in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If a session is valid 30 days from it's creation and you only want to select valid sessions, you need to check, that the creation is in the past but not more than 30 days past now.

```
SELECT *
       FROM seeions
       WHERE timestamp < utc_timestamp()
             AND timestamp >= utc_timestamp() - INTERVAL 30 DAY;
```